# One or more unexpected \r (^M) found;better to use only a \n [whitespace/newline] [1]?

Tags: c++, c++14, indentation

Whenever I am compiling my cpp file on LMS and in return Style error  is coming with this sentence. One or more unexpected \r (^M) found;better to use only a \n  [whitespace/newline] [1]??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your compiler is complaining about CRLF-encoded files (DOS/Windows) instead of LF-only, as per UNIX/POSIX conventions.

You may need to adjust your editor to save in the correct format.

Comment: Brother How can I do that?

Comment: If my code is..

Comment: Depends on your editor. It's a setting in most.

Comment: // Copyright 2020 Minxuan Cai
#include<string>

Comment: Editor, not code. Editor.

Comment: it just Showing error on the very beginning..

Comment: Every single line will have this problem if you have CRLF issues.

Comment: @HafeezcsWhiz The code is irrelevant, it's the editor settings that matter.

Comment: Suggest me any editor where I can set this code..I have done this code on DevC++ .

Comment: Check the DevC++ settings. I've never used that before, but there should be a "file encoding" settings option.

Comment: For me this helped: just try retyping your code manually, you may have copied it from an editor with different format. just retype it in the editor you run your spelling checker on.